# Intersection of groups on testng.xml

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, beanshell

Hi i'm trying to make a groups intersection inside testng.xml however when i run the maven command i have a NullPointerException.

here is the suite:

```
<test name="test">
    <method-selectors>
        <method-selector>
            <script language="beanshell"><![CDATA[
            runTest = false;
            groupIn = System.getProperty("includeGroups");
            groupNotIn = System.getProperty("excludeGroups");

            if ((groupIn == null) || (groupIn == "")) {
                runTest = false;
            } else {
                StringTokenizer groupsTagList = new StringTokenizer(groupIn, ",");
                runTest = true;

                while (groupsTagList.hasMoreTokens()) {
                  if (!(groups.containsKey(groupsTagList.nextToken())))
                    runTest = false;
                }

                if (runTest && (groupNotIn != null) && (groupNotIn != "")) {
                    StringTokenizer groupsNotInList = new StringTokenizer(groupNotIn, ",");

                    while (groupsNotInList.hasMoreTokens()) {
                       if ((groups.containsKey(groupsNotInList.nextToken())))
                         runTest = false;
                    }
                 }
            }
            return runTest;
            ]]>
            </script>
        </method-selector>
    </method-selectors>
    <packages>
        <package name="tests.*"></package>
    </packages>
</test>
```

the output:

```
ERROR in execution: java.lang.NullPointerException
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.402 sec - in TestSuite
```

Command:

```
 mvn -DSELENIUM_IS_LOCAL=true -Dbrowser=firefox -Dhub=http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub clean test -DincludeGroups=groupA,groupB
```

Comment: What is the exception stacktrace?

Comment: ERROR in execution: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: That is just a message with an exception type. A stacktrace contains the contents of the call stack at the moment the exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but the suite wasn't executed, that is the only message in console.

Comment: @migueldelgado Can you please try increasing the log verbosity by setting "verbose" to 2 or higher at the suite level attribute ? I don't think there is any issue with your beanshell method selector but perhaps the NPE is arising out of somewhere else. The entire stacktrace is what is going to help...

Comment: Please check https://medium.com/@edwarddubilyer/testng-life-without-xml-changing-test-discovery-logic-2d8c0c6183eb for the programmatic way to implement the intersection.